# React native API request with fetch() to getmati API respond well in postman, but not working in App and got 400 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I am trying to integrate mati api for KYC flow into my React native app.
In order to get auth token, I referenced the documentation below.
https://docs.getmati.com/reference/authentication
Testing in postman works fine and got the response of auth_token.
However, in the React native code, it got 400 error.
Please help me figure this out.
The code snippet:

```
const myoptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Authorization:
          'Basic AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({grant_type: 'client_credentials'}),
    };

    fetch('https://api.getmati.com/oauth', myoptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The error is:

```
 LOG  {"code": 400, "message": "Missing parameter: `grant_type`", "name": "invalid_request", "status": 400, "statusCode": 400}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation you mentioned it seems like its accepting form data and you are sending search params. Try this

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("grant_type","client_credentials");

const myoptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    Authorization:
      'Basic AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
  },
  body: formData,
};

fetch('https://api.getmati.com/oauth', myoptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't working, too.

Comment: you are receiving the same error?

Comment: ``` [TypeError: Network request failed]```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error and figured out as below.

```
const body = new URLSearchParams({grant_type: 'client_credentials'});
const myoptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Authorization:
          'Basic AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
      },
      body: body.toString(),
    };

    fetch('https://api.getmati.com/oauth', myoptions)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

In react native, we must send the body as string, it works well and get the right response.
Thank you.